How to debug "FATAL: database "ag_test3" does not exist" in postgres?
I have a simple postgresql 12.19 installation on my Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS virtual server. The generic postgres packages are installed:
postgresql-12/focal-updates,now 12.19-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed] postgresql-client-12/focal-updates,now 12.19-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
postgresql-client-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,now 214ubuntu0.1 all [installed,automatic]
postgresql-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,now 214ubuntu0.1 all [installed,automatic]
On day 1, I created a database called "ag_test3".
On day 10 for example, I deleted the database called "ag_test3".
Now, after "systemctl restart postgresql" and any day after the first day, my logfile "/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log" is getting filled with this following error, which I do not understand where it originates from or which postgres-process is causing this:
2024-08-20 15:50:39.729 MEST [23464] postgres@ag_test3 LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=ag_test3
2024-08-20 15:50:39.729 MEST [23464] postgres@ag_test3 FATAL:  database "ag_test3" does not exist
I have no application or extensions like pgbouncer that is connected to this server. I believe it is my postgres unix socket, which is doing something that I am not able to figure out. I have tried vacuuming, reindexing and reading the log errors from "/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log" with settings in my postgresql.conf such as:
autovacuum = off
log_statement = all
log_min_error_statement = DEBUG5 (tried all of them including FATAL)
log_connections = on
Yet, I still get this error. The server is otherwise going OK and I have no issues with other databases existing on this server.
What is my postgres-server trying to do and what do I need to look at in order to understand this "FATAL" error message? I should have no problem deleting a database "drop database ag_test3" with psql using my postgres-unix user on that server.
I tried to create a database on day 1, delete a database on day 10, and assume there shall be no error-message in "/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log" normally. No application or client is trying to connect to this server and database.

This ... connection authorized: user=postgres database=ag_test3 says there is an application trying to connect to the database. I would guess some sort of monitoring software. Look at the times for the connection attempts and see if they are regularly spaced.

To make it worse, why is a superuser trying to connect to a non-existing database? A superuser role should only be used by humans for exceptions that can not be handled by normal roles. Never by a script/program. Advice: Change the password for your superuser postgres

I was giving this a second look and you were right. It was the munin-node that is somehow using the postgres-unix socket to access a list that is not updated.
My postgres user is passwordless. I log in to my server with "kssh servername" through ansible, ans then 'su - postgres' and 'psql' as postgres user directly.

If  the postgres user has no password and munin-node is connecting via socket then in pg_hba.conf local is set up with trust authentication or is running as postgres and authentication is set to peer. Spend some time reading this pg_hba.conf.

Yes, local is setup with postgres and authentication with peer. I was not aware of munin-node using this as access/authentication method. I will read up on this as well, thanks!
